# How to fill json in table using javascript. Without repeating repeated id and appending it to the tr

Tags: javascript, json

Json Format :

```
[
  {
    "EmpId": 1,
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Status": "P",
    "StatusDate": "01/01/2017"
  },
  {
    "EmpId": 1,
    "Name": "Abc",
    "Status": "A",
    "StatusDate": "01/02/2017"
  },
  {
    "EmpId": 2,
    "Name": "Xyz",
    "Status": "P",
    "StatusDate": "01/01/2017"
  },
  {
    "EmpId": 2,
    "Name": "Xyz",
    "Status": "P",
    "StatusDate": "01/02/2017"
  }
]
```

Table Format :

I want to create dynamic table using javascript and I want the table format as shown in the image:
[image]

Comment: What si the code you already written?

Comment: Maintain an array of the values you have added, which can be checked to determine if a duplicate has already been added.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I want code to append tr and td dynamically to table using javascript becuase I am getting this code in json and I am iterating loop for it. Can you give the code snippet?

Comment: You need to do some research and make an attempt yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
I highly recommend utilizing lodash.js and their uniqBy function
LoDash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#uniqBy
JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/671qucpd/

Code

    var data = [ { "EmpId": 1, "Name": "Abc", "Status": "P", "StatusDate": "01/01/2017" }, { "EmpId": 1, "Name": "Abc", "Status": "A", "StatusDate": "01/02/2017" }, { "EmpId": 2, "Name": "Xyz", "Status": "P", "StatusDate": "01/01/2017" }, { "EmpId": 2, "Name": "Xyz", "Status": "P", "StatusDate": "01/02/2017" } ];

    console.log(data);

    var unique = _.uniqBy(data, 'EmpId');

    console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```js
var tempObj = [];
arry.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (tempObj.indexOf(obj.EmpId) === -1) {
    tempObj.push(obj.EmpId);
    $('#table1 tbody').append('<tr><td>' + obj.EmpId + '</td><td>' + obj.Name + '</td><td>' + obj.Status + '</td><td>' + obj.StatusDate + '</td></tr>');
  }
});
```